# PHP variable overriding preceding variable

Tags: php, class

I'm working on a script based on a template that was provided to me by my client. The objective is to gather data from a POST request, compile it, and send it to a third party application.

The nature of the data means that there will often be multiple instances of a particular group of variables, for example Current Address, Previous Address and Employer Address.

In the code below, a new object is defined for each address type. A simple example:

```
//set the variables from POST
$address_line_1 = $_POST['currentaddress'];
$prev_add_line_1 = $_POST['previousaddress'];
$emp_add_line_1 = $_POST['employeraddress'];

//create the request and set credentials
$request = new stdClass();
$request->request->Credentials->Username = $username;
$request->request->Credentials->Password = $password;
$request->request->Credentials->Account = $account;

//set classes for multiple address and populate with data for compiling
$address = new stdClass();
$address->AddressType = 'Current';
$address->Line1 = $address_line_1;

$address = new stdClass();
$address->AddressType = 'Previous';
$address->Line1 = $prev_add_line_1;

$address = new stdClass();
$address->AddressType = 'Employer';
$address->Line1 = $emp_add_line_1;

$customer->Addresses = array($address);
$request->request->Proposal->Customers = array($customer);

return $request;
```

The issue I'm having is that if this is submitted, the most recently defined variable is overriding the first two, so they're getting ignored and therefore are not being sent to the third party application (the request then gets rejected as a result for not having the required information).

There are other types of objects that must be defined in this project as well, such as:

```
$primary_customer_name = $_POST['primaryname'];
$secondary_customer_name = $_POST['secondaryname'];

$customer = new stdClass();
$customer->CustomerType = 'Primary';
$customer->Name = $primary_customer_name;

$customer = new stdClass();
$customer->CustomerType = 'Secondary';
$customer->Name = $secondary_customer_name;
```

Again, same issue here where the secondary customer is overriding the primary customer.

I'm not sure what I'm missing, hopefully somebody can point out my obvious glaring error.

If more information is required please let me know and I will update this post.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you want diffrent customer why you have same variable

Comment: You have to learn the difference between a class and an object. You are not defining any class here. You are instantiating objects of type stdClass.

Comment: Of course it's been overwritten. You're using the same variable: $address = X; $address = Y; Guess what's $address value is.. you got it - Y.

Comment: Just a note: You never _define_ a class in your code, you are using an instance of the  `stdClass()` and add dynamically properties to it. a class definetion looks like: `class customer {  public  $CustomerType; public $Name;  }`

Comment: Thanks all for your comments so far. As I said, this was provided to me in the form of a template by my client, and I was instructed to work with it. Mostly all I have done is defined the variables from the POST request. Any suggestions please on what I should do to address this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are over writing the variable.

For example: the following would have `$a` defined as 2. The second statement would overwrite the first.

```
$a = 1;
$a = 2;
```

So what you need to do is define the additional variable under a different identifier.

For example:

```
$address = new stdClass();
$address->AddressType = 'Current';
$address->Line1 = $address_line_1;

$address2 = new stdClass();
$address2->AddressType = 'Previous';
$address2->Line1 = $address_line_1;
```

In addition you are only referencing the single `$address` when creating the the following array. You need to reference all of the values:

```
$customer->Addresses = array($address, $address2);
```

Comment: Thank you - this makes sense. I'll give it a whirl and get back.